# Count the consecutive 1-bit without overlapping

Tags: c

Determine the number of 1-bit pairs without overlap with other pairs in C. But My code does not include the first number. Like 11011 has 2 pairs of 1-bit but my output gives me 1 pair because it did not include the first number.

```
int numPairs(int n){
    int count=0;
    bool prevOne=0;
    while(n!=0){
        bool currOne=(n&1)==1;
        if(currOne && !prevOne)
            count++;
        n=n>>1;
        prevOne=!currOne;
    }
    return count/2;
}
```

Comment: Why not mask with `11` and skip 2 bits if found (one if not)?

Comment: Did you mean to say `prevOne=currOne`? Why are you dividing by 2?

Comment: Could you edit your title or your text, as one talks about counting pairs, and one about counting the number of consecutive '1' which I would say is 4 for 1111, but it's only 2 pairs of '1'. And/or add another example of results expected for 11110111

Answer (score 2):

```
int numPairs(int n)
{ 
    int count=0; 
    bool prevOne=0; // 1 if previous bit was 1.
    while(n!=0)
    { 
        bool currOne=(n&1)==1; 
        if(currOne && prevOne) 
            count++; 
        n=n>>1; 
        prevOne=currOne; 
    } 
    return count; // no need divide count by 2 as count exactly specifies number of 1bit pairs.
}
```

Comment: nice answer, However, we would like to be able to easily read/understand it.  A major step in the understanding is if it were properly indented.  Suggest 1) always include the optional braces '{}" 2) indent after every opening brace '{'.  3) unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: I usually indent my code. But could not find any efficient way of doing it when writing answer from android.

Comment: I modified your answer by inserting the appropriate indentation